# Reverse Proxy browser not recognized/incompatible

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have reverse proxy setup(apache2) that points to a Cloud9 installation.  The proxy is working correctly in that the Cloud9 Site comes up. But Cloud9 requires a specific browser version and states that the browser is not compatible.  I have tested with the latest firefox and chrome.

I don't have very much experience with Apache and reverse proxies but my guess is that the proxy is obscuring the browser version.  How do I forward this information on? or spoof a known working version?

Answer (score 1):

When reverse proxying to a backend server using apache's mod_proxy, the apache server performs standard RFC 2616-compliant HTTP Proxy requests to the backend server.

This means that the exact request data (method, headers and body) are passed through to the backend, with the addition of an X-Forwarded-For: header that contains the original client's IP.

Apache does not "make up" anything in the forwarded request.

Put a CGI page on the cloud9 backend that shows all request headers, then compare them with your browser headers.

Comment: So do you think it is a Cloud9 problem then?

Comment: I think you need to troubleshoot and determine what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks,  I am very new to all of this.  Are there any good articles on how to troubleshoot the backend?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Cloud9 using absolute paths (not cool) in their HTML pages. If you open the developer tools in Chrome you can see a long list of 404 errors.

I worked around the problem by using some Apache rewrite rules:

My current Apache configuration:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule   ^/socket.io/(.*) /editor/socket.io/$1 [P]
 RewriteRule   ^/static/(.*) /editor/static/$1 [P]
 RewriteRule   ^/workspace/(.*) /editor/workspace/$1 [P]

 ProxyPass /editor/ http://127.0.0.1:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse /editor/ http://127.0.0.1:3000/
 <Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```